# Moq em c# métodos de classes diferentes

Tags: c#, .net, testes-de-unidade, mock, moq

Boa noite.

Sou novato em testes unitários.
Gostaria de pedir ajuda para solucionar uma dúvida.

Possuo o seguinte método de uma classe que chama o método de outra classe:

```
class public Teste: ITeste
{
   private readOnly ITeste _teste;

   public Teste( ITeste _trans)
   {
      this._teste = _trans;
   }

   public List<Carteira> ObterFila(TimeSpan horaCorte)
   {
      List<Carteira> lstCarteiraInfo = new List<Carteira>();
      lstCarteiraInfo = new DataAcces.Transacao.ObterFilaAlerta(horaCorte);
      return lstCarteiraInfo;
   }
}
```

Gostaria de testar esta classe mockando o método ObterFilaAlerta que está dentro da biblioteca de classes, na classe Transacao e na camada DataAcces.
(A classe Transacao possui interface ITransacao)

Tentei o seguinte código e não obtive sucesso:

```
[TestClass]
    public class TesteMoq
    {
        private Mock<DataAcces.Interface.ITransacao> _mock;
        private Mock<Business.Interface.ITeste> _mockB;

    [TestMethod]
    public void Valida()
    {
        _mock = new Mock<DataAcces.Interface.ITransacao>();
        _mockB = new Mock<Business.Interface.ITeste>();

        Lista<Carteira> lista = new Lista<Carteira>;

        _mock.Setup(x => x.ObterFilaAlerta(It.IsAny<TimeSpan>())).Returns(lista);
        Business.Teste teste = new Business.Teste(_mock.Object);
        var resultado = teste.ObterAlerta();
        var resultadoEsperado = new Lista<Carteira>;

       Assert.AreEqual(resultado, resultadoEsperado);
    }
}
```

Quando depuro esse teste a chamada do método ObterFilaAlerta não está sendo mockada e é executada a implementação.

Poderiam me ajudar com algum exemplo parecido?

Comment: pq sua classe injeta a própria interface? não entendi